# Vue - анимация img src

Tags: vue.js

Есть простой компонент изображения

```
<custom-comp :bg_img="bg_img"></custom-comp>
```

Внутри там обычный div с шириной 100% и высотой 500px, которому через стили присваивается background-image = bg_img

Нужно сделать анимацию слайдера.
При изменении фонового изображения - "старое" уезжает в право, "новое" выезжает слева.

Пробовал разные примеры из документации transition-ов. Но получается только заанимировать появление нового изображение, старое просто исчезает. Либо есть анимация появления и исчезновения, но только в это время, одновременно, видно сразу 2 изображения, "старое" - с анимацией исчезновения и "новое" с анимацией появления.

В общем буду рад рабочему примеру.

Comment: Я ошибся в заголовке, конечно же анимация НЕ img src а background-image. Но особой роли это не играет.

Comment: https://awesome-vue.js.org/components-and-libraries/ui-components.html#carousel - рабочие примеры на любой вкус